# How to count file downloads?

Tags: php, file, count, apache2, tracking

I have simple php upload form which uploads files to specific directory.

I will eventually run out of space and I would like to see which files are being downloaded, which aren't and remove files which haven't been downloaded for a certain amount of time.

I am trying to grep those in access logs but its nearly impossible. I tried parse logs and have a clue but I didn't find it comfortable enough as there are lot of logs to parse (other virtual hosts logs and sht load of compressed ones)

Is there a simple way to keep track of files being downloaded?

I also tried to make separate log file for upload directory only, but haven't succeeded. Could not make it work im quite new with servers.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You can add extra layer to count downloads (eg `readfile()` or `Location`). And how you try configure for access log? (You can add subdomain for download directory, and there adding log is verry simple)

Comment: How can I add extra layer? I did try to configure access log by man page but was unable to understand how to do it. I found some articles but their settings were different from mine.

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/